# Install Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: 16.04, oracle, sqldeveloper

I'm trying to install Oracle SQL Developer on Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed [the following guide to install it](https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu/)

I also tried to download the RPM file from Oracle and convert it to DEB, and install that. However I get the same fault as the above method.

The fault is really weird. I do not get an error message of any kind. The installation goes OK. But when I try to launch the application, the GUI quickly flashes on the screen for less than a second.

When I try to launch it using the console the only output I get is:
[image: error]

Do any of you have an idea on how to solve this, or how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Running the .sh :

the guides are ok but  bit vague

I take it you're using alien ?

this guy is more thorough in his explenation :

https://youtu.be/dWnAizA1bYE

The issue (I think) is that executable rights need to be added and you need to cd to the folder and run the script not just type sqldeveloper like you're doing.

it so happens that this is one of the simplest setups for .desktop files so you can make yourself one with your own custom icon for convenience : https://askubuntu.com/a/398669/307184

for safety's sake uninstall it first via `apt remove sqldeveloper` and run the guide from this guy's video step by step.

Comment: I tried following the guide you linked to. I get to around the 12:40 mark. There I get the same fault as stated earlier. Nothing is launching. It closes immediately. Is there a log file somewhere I can look into?

Comment: sorry I though he did it like this: try this : https://youtu.be/r-4OlbUB3z4

Comment: I just tried to restore a snapshot of the VM that was running Ubuntu, and tried following the first guide you posted. The guide was pretty identical to what I tried already. What seemed to make a difference was restoring the snapshot. Gonna accept your answer anyway :).

Comment: thanks ! how should I edit my post or will the youtube guide work for anyone?

Comment: I think the reason for the fault was me trying to install using alien, before doing what you wrote in the answer. The only thing I would sugest doing, is to write down what he is explaining in the video, should the video be taken down, or the link dies.