# Invalid .desktop file

Tags: .desktop

I have a simple script I want to be able to run from a Desktop entry on Ubuntu 19.10. I followed [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/a/398669/711343) and created a `.desktop` file but I'm getting an error saying it is invalid. Here is the error

[image]

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
lsusb
read -p ""
```

And here is the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=lsusb
Comment=Comment
Exec=/home/user/lsusb.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application 
Icon=
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: This might sound weird but try removing extra space after `Application` in `Type`. I tried this desktop entry on my system running 1.04 and it fails if there's a space after `Application`.

Comment: @Kulfy Turns out not that weird. That was exactly the issue. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Kulfy, good catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From comments:

The error was because of extra whitespace after `Application` in `Type` key. It seems `Application`  (notice the extra whitespace) isn't an identified value for `Type` key in desktop entry.